# Django: Getting succefully deleted message even if deletion is prevented

Tags: python, django, django-admin

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    end = models.DateTimeField()

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        if self.end < now:
            return  # past events cannot be deleted

        super(SomeModel, self).delete(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

I've wrote above code in one of my models.
It's working beautifully but having one single problem:

I'm getting a message saying, object is successfully deleted even if that model is not deleted because if the condition I put in.

Is there a way I can send a message that object is not deleted in this case?

NB: This model is for django-admin only.

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible since the code that displays the message doesn't check for the return value from `delete`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delete view in the django admin does not check to see if the `delete()` call was successful, so if you want to override the delete method as in your question, you'll need to override the entire [`ModelAdmin.delete_view`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.delete_view) method.

If `SomeModel` is only used in the Django admin, another possible approach is to override the [`has_delete_permission`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_delete_permission) method. This would remove the delete links from the change view, and disable the delete page for events in the past.

```
class SomeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        """
        Return False for events in the past
        """
        if obj is None:
            # obj is None in the model admin changelist view
            return False
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        if obj.end < now:
            return False # past events cannot be deleted
        else:
            return super(SomeModelAdmin, self).has_delete_permission(request, obj)
```

The implementation above would disable the "delete selected objects" [admin action](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#admin-actions), as we return False when obj is None. You should consider doing this anyway, as it calls the queryset delete method and not your overridden delete method.

With this approach, superadmins would still be able to delete events as they have all permissions. I don't think this approach would work if `SomeModel` appears in model inlines -- although I see that `has_delete_permission` is an `InlineModelAdmin` option in Django 1.4.

Comment: Thank you. This is a save.

I gone for overriding has_delete_permission, because I use it only in admin.

I already overridden get_action() to disable 'delete selected object' action. So this is not an issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could return True or False from your overridden delete() and just work with the value of that within your form to build your message.

```
def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if self.end < now:
        return False  # past events cannot be deleted

    super(SomeModel, self).delete(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return True #successfully deleted from the database
```

Comment: This is not working either. I tried this before.

I'm using Django 1.3.1, If that helps.